# How to fetch value from objects in laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I m making an app in which I want to get value of an object and also I want to get id while creating new user.

I was using drop down menu, and want to get id which was selected in previous dropdown.

```
@php

  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

  $uid=DB::table('users')->where('role_id','4')->get();
  $counter=0;
  $cid=DB::table('classses')->get();
  $counterr=0;
  $sec=DB::table('sections')->where('class_id',array('class_id' => $cid->id('class_id')))->get();
  $counterrr=0;
@endphp

  <select user="" name="parent_id">
       <option value="null">User</option>
            @foreach($uid as $user)
               @if($counter==0)
                  <option selected="selected" value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
                       {{$counter++}}
               @else
                 <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
               @endif
            @endforeach
   </select>
   <div class="col-md-6">
       <select class="" name="class_id">
             <option value="null">Class</option>
             @foreach($cid as $cc)
                 @if($counterr==0)
                    <option selected="selected" value="{{$cc->id}}">{{$cc->title}}</option>
                    {$counterr++}}
                 @else
                     <option value="{{$cc->id}}">{{$cc->title}}</option>
                 @endif
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <select section="" name="section_id">
               <option value="null">Section</option>
               @foreach($sec as $sc)
                   @if($counterrr==0)
                       <option selected="selected" value="{{$sc->id}}">{{$sc->title}}</option>
                       {{$counterrr++}}
                   @else
                       <option value="{{$sc->id}}">{{$sc->title}}</option>
                   @endif
                @endforeach
        </select>
```

As now I want that the object shows the value of selected id in class-dropdown menu and I want to put it in selected list of section

```
$sec=DB::table('sections')->where('class_id',$cid)->get();
```

I' m having issues in writing syntax over here.('class_id',**$cid**)

Also I want that a id on which this new user is going to be created , how to get that?

Comment: You may try this code 
$cid=DB::table('classses')->get();
$cids = $cid->pluck('id');
$counterr=0;
$sec=DB::table('sections')->where('class_id',$cids)->get();

Comment: this is not working with my project it is only showing one key in section, I want section should show all the keys where class_id = the selected by user..